# PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException java

Tags: java, ssl, soap

I am trying to post to an https soap endpoint, but I am getting the below exception.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have tried the below commands to add the certificate to cacerts

```
keytool -genkey -alias notification-adapter_private -keyalg RSA -keystore notification-adapter.jks -keysize 1024

keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias notification-adapter_private -file notification-adapter.csr -keystore notification-adapter.jks

keytool -exportcert -alias notification-adapter_private -keystore notification-adapter.jks -file notification-adapter.cer

keytool -import -alias notification-adapter_private -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file notification-adapter.cer
```

```
    package com.nokia.dpa.ChangeDeviceTrigger.post;

    import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class PostSoapHttps {
        private static String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:chan=\"http://dpa.nokia.com/ChangeDeviceTrigger/\">\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "      <chan:ChangeDeviceTrigger>\n" +
                "         <SRVChangeDeviceTrigger>\n" +

                "         </SRVChangeDeviceTrigger>\n" +
                "      </chan:ChangeDeviceTrigger>\n" +
                "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "notification-adapter.jks";
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //System.out.println(request);

            try {
                URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME);
                File file = new File(resource.getFile());
                String keyPath = file.getAbsoluteFile().toString();
                System.out.println(keyPath);
                String keyPass = "vodafoneit123";
                String keyType = "JKS";


                //path to SSL keystore

                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyPath);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyPass);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", keyType);


                //post XML over HTTPS
                URL url = new URL("https: url"); //replace
                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput( true );


                connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "text/xml"  );
                connection.setRequestProperty( "SOAPAction", ""  );
                connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
                {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                connection.connect();

                //tell the web server what we are sending
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(request);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                // reading the response
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
                int num;
                while ( -1 != (num=reader.read( cbuf )))
                {
                    buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
                }
                String result = buf.toString();
                System.out.println(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.7\lib\idea_rt.jar=53820:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.7\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\manjosh\Documents\Process\New_Project\DECCMVODVFDMCDCDP18A\NotificationAdapter\notification-adapter\target\classes;C:\opt\maven_repo\axis\axis\1.3\axis-1.3.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\axis\axis-jaxrpc\1.3\axis-jaxrpc-1.3.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\axis\axis-saaj\1.3\axis-saaj-1.3.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.5.1\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.0.4\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\commons-discovery\commons-discovery\0.2\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\javax\mail\mail\1.4.1\mail-1.4.1.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.11.0\log4j-core-2.11.0.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.0\log4j-api-2.11.0.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.11.0\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.0.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-alpha2\slf4j-api-1.8.0-alpha2.jar;C:\opt\maven_repo\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar" com.nokia.dpa.ChangeDeviceTrigger.post.PostSoapHttps
    C:\Users\manjosh\Documents\Process\New_Project\DECCMVODVFDMCDCDP18A\NotificationAdapter\notification-adapter\target\classes\notification-adapter.jks
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
        at com.nokia.dpa.ChangeDeviceTrigger.post.PostSoapHttps.main(PostSoapHttps.java:91)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 17 more

    Process finished with exit code 0
```